# What is the difference between Exception, InvalidArgumentException or UnexpectedValueException?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, throw

When should I use Exception, InvalidArgumentException or UnexpectedValueException?

I don't know the real different between them as I always used Exception.

Comment: see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-hierarchies.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Different exceptions just give you more granularity and control over how you catch and handle exceptions.

Consider a class where you are doing many things - e.g. getting input data, validating input data and then saving it somewhere. You might decide that if the wrong or empty arguments are passed to the `get()` method, you might throw an `InvalidArgumentException`. When validating, if something is out of the ordinary or doesn't match up you could throw an `UnexpectedValueException`. If something totally unexpected happens you could throw a standard `Exception`.

This becomes useful when you are catching, as you can handle different types of exceptions in different ways. For example:

```
class Example
{
    public function get($requiredVar = '')
    {
        if (empty($requiredVar)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Required var is empty.');
        }
        $this->validate($requiredVar);
        return $this->process($requiredVar);
    }

    public function validate($var = '')
    {
        if (strlen($var) !== 12) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Var should be 12 characters long.');
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function process($var)
    {
        // ... do something. Assuming it fails, an Exception is thrown
        throw new Exception('Something unexpected happened');
    }
}
```

In the above example class, when calling it you could `catch` multiple types of exceptions like so:

```
try {
    $example = new Example;
    $example->get('hello world');
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    var_dump('You forgot to pass a parameter! Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    var_dump('The value you passed didn\'t match the schema... Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump('Something went wrong... Message: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

In this case you get an `UnexpectedValueException` like this: `string(92) "The value you passed didn't match the schema... Exception: Var should be 12 characters long."`.

It should also be noted that [these exception classes all end up extending from Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) anyway, so if you don't define special handlers for the `InvalidArgumentException` or others then they will be caught by `Exception` catchers anyway. So really, why not use them?